# Problem installing MathPSfrag

Tags: packages, installing

I am trying to install MathPSfrag and I'm going through the MathPSfrag-Test.nb included in the download.
The notebook asks me to input the paths to certain executables.
My input looks like this:

```
  SetOptions[UnPSfrag,
  GhostscriptExecutable -> 
   "C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs8.70\\bin\\gswin32c.exe", 
   LaTeXExecutable -> 
   "C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.8\\miktex\\bin\\latex.exe",    
  DvipsExecutable -> 
   "C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.8\\miktex\\bin\\dvips.exe"];
```

I'm on a Windows Vista machine and quite sure that the paths are correct, but the notebook fails to find the programs.

Has someone installed MathPSfrag succesfully under Windows and knows the right paths, or is there some obvious mistake?

Comment: Use for spaces (or the `101010` button) to mark a block as code. Then the backslashes show up fine.

Comment: Is this sorted?  Why are the path separators in your input doubled: if they are input to a test program I would think they do not need to be escaped.  Have you tried using the usual forward slash as path separator?  It may be that the program expects native paths.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue in the meantime? It doesn't look like you are going to get an answer here. The question could be migrated to a sister site, e.g. http://superuser.com which handles software installation problems.

Comment: I'm tending to close this question as "too localized". Please advice if it is still an issue.

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem, but currently it's no longer an issue for me. You may close it.

Comment: @Emerson: I'm confused - is the problem still about or not?